# VSCode custom macros

Tags: visual-studio-code, macros, latex, keyboard-shortcuts

I am currently trying to experiment with using VSCode at the moment, and i cannot figure out how to properly define macros and bind them to specific keybinds.

I am used to using Sublime text, and i have defined a few macros that help me type much quicker and make less mistakes

**The macros that i would like to get are the following:**

1. *alt+shift+q* : which types `\(\)` and set the cursor in the middle (between the first `(` and the second `\`).
2. *alt+shift+s* : which types `\[\]` and set the cursor in the middle (between the first `[` and the second `\`). Additionally, if it is possible, i would like it to also toggle a math preview function using `latex-workshop.toggleMathPreviewPanel`.
3. *alt+shift+a* : which types the following

```
\begin{align*}
    \item 
\end{align*}
```

The `\item` is preceded by a `tab`, and it sets the cursor after the `\item`

I have managed to get the first macro by doing as follows

- Installing the macros package by geddski.
- Creating the following macro, and inserting it in the `settings.json`:

```
"macros": {
        "latex_inline_math": [
            {
                "command": "type",
                "args": {
                    "text": "\\(\\)"
                }
            },
            "cursorLeft",
            "cursorLeft"
        ],
}
```

- Binding it to the keybind by inserting in the `keybindings.json` like this:

```
{ // to get \(\)
    "key": "alt+shift+q",
    "command": "macros.latex_inline_math"
},
```

But i cannot figure out how to get the macros 2. and 3.

> Also, if there is a better way to write the macro that i wrote, please let me know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define the following 3 keybindings

```
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+q",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": { "snippet": "\\($0\\)" }
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+s",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": { "snippet": "\\[$0\\]" }
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+a",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": { "snippet": "\\begin{align*}\n\t\\item$0\n\\end{align*}" }
  }
```

If you also want a preview you can use the extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

Define this key binding

```
  
{
    "key": "shift+alt+s",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
        "sequence": [
            "latex-workshop.toggleMathPreviewPanel",
            { "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": { "snippet": "\\[$0\\]" } }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: @needle See my update, if it solves the problem you can mark the question solved