# R / VSCode / Radian: Comma at end of line breaks execution

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use VSCode for R scripts, along with the Radian terminal.  I'm on Mac OS 10.14.6 (Mojave). Installation went fine.  But now when I try to execute a multi-line block of code, if a line of code ends with a comma then the code to that point gets sent to the console as a complete statement, which of course generates an error.  I've read https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/437, but it doesn't seem to be addressing the same thing.

Here's a quick example of something that causes the problem:

```
mydf <- data.frame("Cat" = c("A", "B", "C"), 
     Values = c(12, 10, 15))
```

Both lines get sent to the console for execution separately, and of course both throw errors.

At the suggestion of a commenter below, here's my settings.json file:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Abyss",
    "editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 100,
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "comments": "#7c9478"
    },
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.selectionBackground": "#0000ff"
    },
    "diffEditor.wordWrap": "on",
    "launch": {

        "configurations": [],
        "compounds": []
    },
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "Chrome",
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
    "r.bracketedPaste": true,
    "r.plot.useHttpgd": true,
    "r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal": true,
    "r.rpath.mac": "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R",
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "r.rterm.mac": "/usr/local/bin/radian",
    "r.rterm.option": [],
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx":{
        "R_HOME": "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
    },
}
```

Any ideas, anyone?  Big thanks.

Comment: you could try the ugly version of simply putting the coma in the next line `argument1=foo *linebreak*    , argument2=bar`

Comment: Yeah, thought of that.  The problem is that VSCode is completing each line automatically.  So the first line of this:

mydf <- data.frame("Cat" = c("A", "B", "C" <LINEBREAK>
        ), Values = c(12, 10, 15))

gets interpreted as 

mydf <- data.frame("Cat" = c("A", "B", "C"))

So then, of course, the next line throws an error.  This is super frustrating -- really surprised that I can't find any others with the same problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with VSCode, but it might be worth a try to enquire about (redefining) language-specific macros, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67267058/20513099

Comment: Maybe this has nothing to do with it, but in your settings.json, do you have `"r.bracketedPaste": true`?

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  @I_O, I don't think this has anything to do with macros or keybindings.  It's happening with code that's entered manually by me just typing it in directly.  and Kat, yes, I do. have my settings.json file with r.bracketdPaste set to true.

Comment: I suggest you delete `r.bracketedPaste`, restart VSC, then add it back, restart and see if it is still an issue. It looks like that's the purpose of that call. (Perhaps look if there's a spelling error, comma for a period, that sort of thing, too.)

Comment: I just had another thought; perhaps it wouldn't be a bad idea to add your settings.json to your question. I'm guessing the answer is in there.

Comment: To your question can you add a short example including (i) some code that produces the problem (the `mydf` example from your comment would be fine although it doesn't look like it has a line ending in a comma?), (ii) where your cursor is, (iii) the name of the command you are using to send the code to radian (not just the keyboard shortcut), and (iv) the complete output from radian including any code after the error? And do you have a `.radian_profile` file? If so can you add the contents of that too?

Comment: Also what version of the R extension are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the comments, everyone. This turned out to be a problem with settings.json scope. I had somehow made the change to r.bracketedPaste (setting it to true) in the user and default settings, but not the workspace settings, where it was still set to false (as you can probably tell, I'm new to vscode). Changing the setting at the workspace level did the trick. Sorry for the false alarm, and thanks again for the suggestions.

Comment: Great that you came back and posted the solution - this can be helpful for people suffering from the same issue in future.