# How do you make a macro with vscode that executes a command (g++ and ./a.out in the same command) in the terminal?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, macros, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to automate vscode so I can work efficiently in c++ with it. But while trying to make macros with the geddski extension, I didn't understand how to execute a command in the terminal, I searched but I have the impression that nobody has the same problem (I read [VSCode custom macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67267058/vscode-custom-macros)).

For now, here's my code in settings.json :

```json
    "macros": {
        "compile": [
            {
                "command": "acces_path/g++.exe",
                "args": [
                    "-Wall",
                    "-Wextra",
                    "-Wshadow",
                    "-Wfatal-errors",
                    "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                    "-g",
                    "${file}",
                    "-o",
                    "a.out"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

But I don't understand why nothing's happening, because I don't think there are any problems...

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

ps: I know there are tasks, but I don't know how to compile and run my program at the same time either, so if you know how to do it, I'd like some explanations.

EDIT : I found, as I could not do everything just with one command and I had to execute the tasks one after the other, I did this:

```json
     {
         "label": "build",
         "type": "cppbuild",
         "command": "access_path/g++.exe",
         "args": [
             "-Wall",
             "-Wextra",
             "-Wshadow",
             "-Wfatal-errors",
             "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
             "-g",
             "${file}",
             "-o",
             "access_path/a.out",
             "&&",
             "access_path/a.out",
             "<access_path/input.in",
             ">access_path/output.in"
         ],
         "problemMatcher": [
             "$gcc"
         ],
         "group": {
             "kind": "build",
             "isDefault": true
         }
      },
```

and now it works, because in fact my a.out program won't run in a loop because there's the input already given (we can't write anything with the tasks) and the output to retrieve the output.

Answer (score 1):

I think [VSCode tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) are what you are looking for.

Example for a tasks.json with a build and run task:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "acces_path/g++.exe",
            "args": [
                    "-Wall",
                    "-Wextra",
                    "-Wshadow",
                    "-Wfatal-errors",
                    "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                    "-g",
                    "${file}",
                    "-o",
                    "a.out"
                ]
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
        },
        {
            "label": "run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "./a.out",
            "dependsOn": ["build"],
        },
    ]
}
```

Notice that the file to be compiled must be active in VSCode. `${file}` will be replaced with the file name that is opened in your IDE (see [variable substitution](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution)).

If you run the task "run" your program will be compiled and then executed. The benefit of the build task is that you get compile errors nicely formatted in the problems view of VSCode (see "problemMatcher").
You can run the task via F1, "Run Task". Or use the Task Explorer extension, for instance. [Key bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_binding-keyboard-shortcuts-to-tasks) are also possible.